# How do I do a clean re-install of zoneminder?

Tags: mysql, linux, uninstallation, dpkg, zoneminder

Because doing this:-

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge zoneminder
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo rm -r /var/www/*
sudo rm -r /etc/apache2/*
sudo rmdir /var/www
sudo rmdir /etc/apache2
sudo rm -r /opt/zm
sudo rm /etc/apache2/conf.d/zoneminder.conf
sudo dpkg --configure -a

reboot hardware

sudo apt-get install zoneminder
```

produces this error:-

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                               apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                                                                                                      [ OK ]
Setting up libapache2-mod-php5 (5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4) ...

Creating config file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini with new version
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                             apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                                                                                                      [ OK ]
Setting up apache2 (2.2.22-6ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up zoneminder (1.25.0-1.1ubuntu1) ...
Starting ZoneMinder: Can't open config file '/opt/zm/etc/zm.conf': No such file or directory at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/ZoneMinder/Config.pm line 100
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/ZoneMinder/Config.pm line 100.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/ZoneMinder.pm line 33.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/ZoneMinder.pm line 33.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/zmpkg.pl line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/zmpkg.pl line 37.
failure

invoke-rc.d: initscript zoneminder, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing zoneminder (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zoneminder
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Originally zoneminder installed "first time" Ok on this 32bit "mint 14" machine using just the single apt-get install zoneminder command from here:-
http://www.tuxradar.com/content/build-your-own-surveillance-zoneminder
 but when I tried to upgrade a couple of days ago to version 1.26.2 by compiling manually, I messed it up.

How can I remove zoneminder completely so that the original "clean" install works again?

Comment: For all those stumbling in on this now : ZoneMinder didn't work for my 15 H.264 and MJPEG cameras. It just killed the CPU so I had to start my own platform. Take a look :) http://shinobi.video . It's worth mentioning if people have this much headache getting it installed.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any of the above, from this link:-
http://pjpramod.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/starting-zoneminder-cant-open-config.html

So I did this:-

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/*
```

and then the install completes OK - but the popups no longer work (don't open at all or open in the same window), so don't do that.

Finally I abandoned re-installing the pre-built package (1.25.0 - or was it 1.25.2?) and downloaded the 1.26.3 tar file and unpacked it and cd'ed into it...
...and ./configure was missing...
...but if you run bootstrap.sh

```
./bootstrap.sh
```

then that (and some other things) magically appear.

Then did this:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/zm --with-mysql=/usr --with-ffmpeg=/usr --with-webuser=www-data --with-webgroup=www-data --disable-debug --disable-crashtrace --enable-mmap=yes --with-webdir=/var/www --with-cgidir=/usr/lib/cgi-bin ZM_SSL_LIB=openssl
```

and it configured OK.

then this

```
sudo make
```

followed by this:-

```
sudo make install
```

and it installed OK but when I tried to run zoneminder I got database errors so did something like this to delete zm:-

```
mysql  -uroot -pyourPassWord
mysql > drop database zm;
mysql > quit;
```

and this to recreate it (I know nothing about databases, this is monkey-see, monkey-do from [here](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Documentation)):-

```
mysql -u root -pyourPassWord
>create database zm;
>exit
mysql -u root -pyourPassWord zm < db/zm_create.sql

mysql -u root -pyourPassWord zm
>grant select,insert,update,delete on zm.* to 'zmuser'@localhost identified by 'zmpass';
>quit
mysqladmin -u root -pyourPassWord reload
```

and it then worked OK (I am running zm like this:-)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/zm start
```

And while trying to figure out what link between apache and zm did (and how apache works etc) I discovered that you only need to do this:-

```
localhost/index.php
```

to bring up zoneminder, working OK, in my browser - Yee Haw! Not bad for two day's effort and one divorce.

But I could only get zmpkg.pl to work by doing this:-

```
sudo /opt/zm/bin/zmpkg.pl
```

and not this:-

```
sudo zmpkg.pl
```

Because, I learn, that that $PATH is defined "globally" for sudo and therefore my adding /opt/zm/bin in my .bashrc file had no effect so then, rather than put zmpkg.pl into /usr/local/sbin (or one of those paths in "global" $PATH) I insert a link instead like this:-

```
sudo ln -s /opt/zm/bin/zmpkg.pl /usr/local/sbin/zmpkg.pl
```

and it works! so now e.g.

```
sudo zmpkg.pl status
```

works again.

Does anyone know how all this should be done? E.g. so that

```
localhost/zm
```

works again?

Update on 20th December 2013: I just upgraded to verion 1.26.5 successfully on this mint 14 system by repeating some of the above instructions i.e.
1) Stop zoneminder.

2) Download version 1.26.5

3) Ran the ./bootstrap.sh script (as mentioned above).

4) Ran the ./configure... script (as mentioned above).

5) Ran the make (as mentioned above - but got errors)...

So I read the README and copied and pasted this from it (line 24):

```
root@host:~# aptitude install -y apache2 mysql-server php5 php5-mysql build-essential libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libpcre3-dev libdbi-perl libarchive-zip-perl libdate-manip-perl libdevice-serialport-perl libmime-perl libpcre3 libwww-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libsys-mmap-perl yasm subversion automake autoconf libjpeg8-dev libjpeg8 apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli libphp-serialization-perl libgnutls-dev libjpeg8-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libavutil-dev libv4l-dev libtool ffmpeg libnetpbm10-dev libavdevice-dev libmime-lite-perl dh-autoreconf dpatch;
```

and then did a
sudo make clean
and then repeated 4) and 5) above and it compiled OK.

6) Did the "sudo make install" OK (i.e. on top of the old version I guess).

7) Then did all the rest of the "as mentioned above" instructions to delete zm from the database (after trying to zm unsuccessfully) and re-inserted it and then it started OK via the "zmpkg.pl start" script as version 1.26.5

8) As before I then had to manually reset up all cameras and password and users and zones but at least it all worked "first time"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have to uninstall all the packages which include LAMP(apache, mysql, php) and zoneminder.

use this command to remove these packages.

```
sudo aptitude purge <pkg-name>
```

Then you have to go to zoneminder manual installation directory (say /usr/src). and use command

```
sudo make clean
sudp updatedb
```

After this you can start normal install procedure.